# "don't" vs "didn't"

Tags: word-choice, differences

Someone sent M a package.
So, M didn't receive the package.

When I asked M, "Have you received the package?"
What should her reply be?

"I don't receive the package", or
"I didn't receive the package"?

Please explain why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

She should say "I haven't received the package".  This implies that there is still a possibility that the package will arrive later; unlike "didn't", which implies that the opportunity to receive the package has passed.

Comment: It wouldn't matter much to me, since we don't have context. It's possibly compounded by the fact that I never have any idea when to expect packages around here.

Comment: Splitting hairs. The question "Have you received the package?" itself is the moment in time which "has passed"

Comment: The opportunity to have received the package *has* passed.

Answer (score 2):

> "I don't receive the package", or "I didn't receive the package"?

//Warning: not a native speaker

"I haven't received the package."

> Please explain why.

Generally answer uses the same verb form as the question. At least textbooks teach English this way.

Q: Did you receive the package?
A: Yes, I did.

Q: Do you accept the package?
A: Yes, I do.

Q: Are you waiting for the package?
A: Yes, I am/yes, we are.

Q: Have you received the package?
A: No, I haven't.

It makes sense to follow this formula, unless want to abruptly change the topic of conversation or something like that.

Comment: "not a native speaker." If you are saying that "I didn't [...]" implies that the respondent is not a native speaker, then this assertion is wrong and unsupportable.

Comment: Instead of giving examples, consider providing grammar rules.

Comment: nice explanation.